# Put component to toolbox when I have component code

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `SeialTabControl` control in my Windows form application.

[image]

On day its component `SerialTabControl1` just disappeared from my form and I don't see it in Toolbox. How to return component back to toolbox when I have it's code.

Comment: You can right click on the Toolbox and choose wich elements get displayed. Does it show up there?

Comment: I don't see it in `.NET Framework Components` tab